# How to enable a file download via anchor in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following:

```
 <a class="download" href='/doc.txt' download>Download txt</a>
```

And this file is in the root of my web project.  When I click, chrome says `Failed - no file`.  How do I let folks download a given file via anchor with MVC?

I've seen some solutions with complex controller logic / Razor - I'm just looking to provide a direct path to a publicly accessible file.

Answer (score 1):

`/` refers to the site root, and `~/` refers to the application root.

So in your case, you more than likely want this:

```
<a class="download" href='~/doc.txt' download>Download txt</a>
```

Comment: Then your path is more than likely incorrect. For example, if the file was in a Content folder of the app, you would need to say: `href="~/Content/doc.txt"`. You can alternatively try an absolute path (i.e., `href="http://www.yoursite.com/doc.txt"`). However, keep in mind that if you change your domain, you might need to change your site. This could happen when you have a separate test and prod domain

Comment: No, it was mime types in my case.